# Lentidão em arquivo arquivo restrito

Tags: php, array, session, libcurl, login

Tenho um arquivo em php processo.php que recebe informações em looping via jquery e faz uma requisição a outra pagina com curl, esse arquivo faz algo em torno de 4 á 5 mil requisições uma por uma, tudo funcionava bem mais depois que restringi o acesso ao arquivo usando sessões por meio do código:

```html
ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["numlogin"])){
    $n1 = $_GET["id"];
    $n2 = $_SESSION["numlogin"];
    if($n1 != $n2) { }

}else{
    header("location:index.html");
}
```

O retorno dos dados ficou lentíssimo antes retornava na tela 2 até 3 json arrays por segundo mais agora a cada 8 segundos retorna uma array somente, creio que é porque ele executa a verificação do session a cada requisição como posso melhorar isso ?

meu processo.php

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);

ob_start();
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["numlogin"])){
    $n1 = $_GET["id"];
    $n2 = $_SESSION["numlogin"];
    if($n1 != $n2) { }

}else{
    header("location:../../../index.html");
}


$dados = $_POST["entrada"];
$nome = explode("|", $dados)[0];
$data = explode("|", $dados)[1];

function GetStr($string, $start, $end){
$str = explode($start, $string);
$str = explode($end, $str[1]);
return $str[0];
}


$ch = curl_init();
$url = "";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "nome=$nome&data=$data");
$resultado = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$valor = GetStr($resultado, '<a href="/logout.html" title="sair" class="btn btnSair">',"</a>"); 

if ($valor == "Sair") {
$dds = array("consulta 1" => $nome, "data" => $data, "resultado" => "existe");
} else {
$dds = array("consulta 4" => $nome, "data" => $data, "resultado" => "nao existe");
}

echo json_encode($dds);

ob_end_flush(); 

?>
```

Comment: Se é o tratamento de sessão que tornou o processamento mais lento, por que não tratar mais de uma requisição ao mesmo tempo? O seu jquery nao pode juntar tudo e mandar num POST só, para o PHP fazer o curl em loop?

Comment: O problema é que isso lagaria muito o servidor por isso mesmo o jquery ja envia linha por linha do lado do cliente, assim fica tudo equilibrado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso possivelmente está ocorrendo porque o `session_start` trava a leitura simultânea. Dois processos não podem ler o mesmo arquivo, sendo assim um mesmo usuário não pode carregar duas páginas ao mesmo tempo enquanto o cURL da primeira não for finalizado.

---

Altere:

```
session_start();
```

Para:

```
session_start();
session_write_close();
```

Isso deve ser suficiente para que outros processos possam ler o mesmo arquivo. Usar o `write_close` apenas diz que não irá gravar nada, mas ainda pode ler a sessão normalmente.

Comment: Obrigado funcionou perfeitamente como o esperado