# Ajuda com Curl PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Tenho uma requisição `cURL` e geralmente a `WebService` que conecto leva 8 segundos para retornar um `JSON` de 600 mil linhas.

O problema está quando abro uma aba para fazer essa requisição

> ex: http://localhost/sistema/busca

Se esta aba estiver carregando e eu tentar abrir outra no mesmo dominio:

> http://localhost/sistema ou http://localhost/sistema/busca

Ela não abre até que o *PHP* acabe de fazer o `cURL`.

Alguém sabe se tem como resolver isso?

Meu código:

```php
    $servidor = "http://localhost:8080/ws/v1/http/servico/disponibilidade";
    $content = str_replace('{idHotel}', $input['idh'], $jsonServ);

    $ch = curl_init($servidor);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($content),
        'Accept: application/json')
    );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo $result;
```

Preciso fazer com que segá permitido fazer duas pesquisas simultâneas em duas ou mais abas.

Comment: Este código é todo o código da página ou existe algo mais além disso? Se tiver algo mais, acho tem uma outra questão com curl mencionando o mesmo problema, [veja se isso resolve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252655/15089).

Comment: @Inkeliz funcionou perfeitamente Obrigado. Realmente era esse o problema meu sistema tem mais código junto.